# Как опустить кнопку "Contact" под изображение

Tags: css, вёрстка

Не могу понять (слишком тупой), как расположить кнопку "Contact" под изображение. Что-бы и изображение и кнопка были справа. На примере ниже все выглядит нормально, но при полнооконном режиме кнопка выползает вверх и становится рядом с изображением (в одной строке). Благодарю за пояснения.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'K2D', sans-serif;
}

nav li {
  border: 2px solid #204156; 
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 5px;  
}

.pic {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.btn {
  background: #51d132;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 60px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px #1e5111;
  transition: .3s;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3daa22;
}

.btn:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px #1e5111;
}

.btn:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 0;
  transition: .3s;
}

.btn:active:after {
  top:-4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Layout</title>
  <link ref="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=K2D" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <h4>Name</h4>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </nav>
  <h1>Text</h1>
  <p>Other text</p>
  <div class="pic"><img src="https://picua.org/images/2018/10/21/fb58b5664e31928fe44b3dcd8e149c9f.md.jpg" alt="nail_picture"></div>
  <br/>
  <div class="btn"><a>Contact</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В верстке я не силен, но это должно помочь)

```css
body {
  font-family: 'K2D', sans-serif;
}

nav li {
  border: 2px solid #204156; 
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 5px;  
}
.clear{
 clear: both;
}
.pic {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.btn {
  background: #51d132;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 60px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px #1e5111;
  transition: .3s;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3daa22;
}

.btn:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px #1e5111;
}

.btn:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 0;
  transition: .3s;
}

.btn:active:after {
  top:-4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Layout</title>
  <link ref="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=K2D" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <h4>Name</h4>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </nav>
  <h1>Text</h1>
  <p>Other text</p>
  <div class="pic"><img src="https://picua.org/images/2018/10/21/fb58b5664e31928fe44b3dcd8e149c9f.md.jpg" alt="nail_picture"></div>

<div class="clear"></div>
  <br/>
  <div class="btn"><a>Contact</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

clearfix в помощь, непонятно использования display: inline-block; при использовании float

```css
body {
  font-family: 'K2D', sans-serif;
}

nav li {
  border: 2px solid #204156; 
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 5px;  
}

.pic {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.btn {
  background: #51d132;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 60px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px #1e5111;
  transition: .3s;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
.clearfix::after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
  }

.btn:hover {
  background: #3daa22;
}

.btn:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px #1e5111;
}

.btn:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 0;
  transition: .3s;
}

.btn:active:after {
  top:-4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Layout</title>
  <link ref="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=K2D" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <h4>Name</h4>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </nav>
  <h1>Text</h1>
  <p>Other text</p>
  <div class="pic"><img src="https://picua.org/images/2018/10/21/fb58b5664e31928fe44b3dcd8e149c9f.md.jpg" alt="nail_picture"></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>

  <br/>
  <div class="btn"><a>Contact</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```